# glyphicon-calendar Start and End Date

Tags: javascript, datetimepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I have this piece of aspx code:

```
<div class="col-xs-2">
    <label for="txtDateActioned" style="cursor: pointer;">Date Actioned</label>
    <div id="sandbox-container">
        <div class="input-group date">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtDateActioned" /><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

From my understanding (and I'm not a web developer, just struggling with maintenance) this is a bootstrap datetime picker.

My humble wish is to set the 'end date' (or 'max date') to 'Today', or any other date. I tried doing this using JS (in the `$(document).ready(function()...)` section):

```
$('#txtDateActioned').daterangepicker(
    {
        maxDate: "01-09-2016"
    }
);
```

However, I can't find a way to make it work. The user can still select a future date, which is exactly what I want to prevent. I also tried different date format such as '2016-09-01', and also tried '`$('#txtDateActioned').datetimepicker()`'. However, nothing worked for me.

Any help is most appreciated.

Elad

Comment: Refer to this - http://www.daterangepicker.com/ . I understand you have included all necessary files for daterange picker to work.  Also, in case of date range picker, you can define the range using 'startDate' and 'endDate' and not 'maxDate'.  'maxDate' is applicable in case of datetimepicker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution:

1) I added an id for the div contains the 'input-group date' class.

```
<div id="dateActionedDP" class="input-group date">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtDateActioned" /><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></span>
</div>
```

2) In js code (the `$(document).ready(function ()`...) I added the following:

```
$("#dateActionedDP").datepicker("setEndDate", '+0d');
```

This worked for me. Thanks everybody for helping.

Elad

Answer (score 0):

You can try **endDate** instead of **maxDate**

> like:- endDate:'+0d'

Answer (score 0):

the example could be

> $('.datepicker').datepicker({
>
> ```
>             format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
>             startDate: '-30y',
>             endDate:'+0d',
>         });
> ```

here the **y** in startDate: '-30y' is indicating the start year of the calender and **d** in endDate:'+0d' is indicating the last date of the calender which is the current date.
you can try this.good luck :)